# Username Availablity check in laravel 5 using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

On my view page if I am entering username after loader.gif is loading but I am not getting the result for username available or not.. pls give me any ideas...

This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
      return view('test/username');
}
public function username()
{
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $users = DB::table('user')
               ->where('username',$username)
               ->first();

    if ($users !== null)
    {
        return true;
    }

        return false;

}
```

These are my routes:

```
Route::get('test/username', 'PageController@index');
Route::post('test/username', 'PageController@username');
```

This is my Blade template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#username").change(function () {
                    $("#message").html("<img src='../images/loader.gif' /> checking...");
                    var username=$("#username").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url: "{{ URL::to('test/username') }}",
                        data: {username:username},
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == 0) {
                                $("#message").html("<img src='../images/yes.png' /> Username available");
                            } else {
                                $("#message").html("<img src='cross.png' /> Username already taken");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
                </td>
                <td id="message"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the point in having an `if`/`else` statement that returns the same view, no matter the result?

Comment: thanks, i tried this one also not working  if ($user== 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

Comment: change data: "username=" + username to data: {username: username}

Comment: thanks, but it is not working,,

Comment: my ajax success function execute only my else condition....

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First of all, you should only check for exact usernames instead of using LIKE, or this could match similar usernames. Start by updating your function to (comments in code):

```
public function username()
{
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $users = DB::table('user')
               ->where('username', $username) // exact matches only
               ->first(); // we only need one result

    // instead of count, check that a valid result is returned
    if ( $users !== null )
    {
        return true;
    }
    // else not required
    return false;
}
```

You need to update your route to call the correct function:

```
Route::post('test/username', 'PageController@username');
```

Next, you need to update your JavaScript to correctly send the data to your PHP script. Update the `data` to:

```
data: { 'username': username },
```

If you still get errors, you may need to update the `name()` function to actually return JSON. You can do this using:

```
return \Response::json( true );
```

Comment: Please provide more details? What are you seeing? Are you getting a error message? Can't help unless you explain further.

Comment: I have tried but in console I have checked my ajax is not sending entered data to controller, please suggest me , I am doing any mistake in ajax or in controller... thanx for your reply..

Comment: Change your route to ```Route::post('test/username', 'PageController@username');```

Comment: Can't help unless you provide better information. What does your ajax call return? What error messages are you seeing? If you javascript code showing syntax errors in your browser?

Comment: Just now I have checked my console it's not showing any error but only one condition(else) is working from my ajax.I think i made mistake in ajax that's why my entered data is not going in controller ,,,please suggest me what I am doing wrong...Thanx for Reply..

Comment: Change ```if (data == 0) {``` to ```if (!data) {```

Comment: this one also tried not working.. whatever i entered the name is not selecting the my database  and also controller,,, i think this is the problem,, please suggest me,,, Thanx for Reply..

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you are not actually calling the `username` function declared in your controller but a `name` one, which doesn't exist. Try modifying your second route to:

```
Route::post('test/username', 'PageController@username');
```